# Did a refugee evade arrest by three female police officers in Sweden, as shown in this video?

Tags: law-enforcement, sweden

[@PeterSweden7](https://twitter.com/PeterSweden7) posted a [video](https://twitter.com/PeterSweden7/status/848597012207611905) with the text:

> SWEDISH POLICE FIASCO: 3 female cops beaten by 1 male refugee after trying to arrest for arson attacks. Police car SMASHED.

The video is apparently a camera-phone recording of an incident where three officers attempt to subdue a violent man armed with rocks, and are unable to hold him down.

I looked for the video on the net and found [this forum entry](https://www.rooshvforum.com/thread-62034.html) that has the same video with a similar claim. This post was [retweeted](https://twitter.com/PrisonPlanet/status/848598707352330241) by Paul Joseph Watson, a nationalist activist, writer, vlogger and editor of infowars.com, the most popular conspiracy theory website.

All of the sources seem to be dubious and right leaning.

Does the video show a refugee and three Swedish female police officers?

Comment: @oddthinking The question asks: does the video shows a refugee and three Swedish female police officers. I explained that based on the video alone it is not possible to tell if the attacker is a refugee, but with high certainty one can say that 3 police officers are female (showed the time when people can see this). You completely ignored it and told totally irrelevant reasons: **You cannot tell whether someone is a refugee from their face** (this is what I told in my answer). **You cannot tell if the video is staged**. The question has not asked it. So why have you removed my answer?

Comment: The question asks whether this person is a refugee. The way to find that out is to look at their legal status, not their face. The parts of your answer that attempted to judge the race and legal status of the two men in the video by their skin colour is a red herring.

Comment: Please see the [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) link for why your opinions on whether the video is fake are off-topic. The intro to your answer explains it isn't an answer, and I agree. Hence, I deleted it as a non-answer.

Comment: @Oddthinking **The question asks whether this person is a refugee**. No, read the question carefully. It asks **Does the video show a refugee and three Swedish female police officers?**. You can't just grab a part of it and ignore another part. Also, if you would look at my answer carefully I have told that you can't say if the person is a refugee. **The intro to your answer explains it isn't an answer**. One more time, read carefully what is written there and do not ignore the parts you didn't like. I wrote: **This is not a proper answer**, which is not the same as not an answer.

Comment: You are playing with semantics. p ∧ q → p. You cannot tell from *looking* at the video whether they are a refugee. What you can do is research, find out who the person was, and whether that person is a refugee. Your post was not a proper answer. It was also not an answer.

Comment: What 'they' are you talking about? There is only one attacker in the video. Anyway, yes I can't tell whether he is a refugee and I clearly stated this in the answer and in my comment. Can you stop using it in your reply? In my not a proper answer which is still an answer, I answered part of the question - whether the police officers on the video are female. If you do not agree with it or have reasonable doubts about it, you are free to downvote and tell why do you believe that my explanation is not enough for you. But I do not think deletion is justifiable.

Comment: @SalvadorDali bottom line, we don't allow (at all) answers of the form "here's my interpretation of the video in question". They are original research and will be deleted. Find evidence *beyond the video* in order to answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event took place in a housing complex for refugees on March 20th in Fagersjö, a suburb just outside Stockholm and received attention in main-stream media as well, e.g. in [Dagens Nyheter](http://www.dn.se/sthlm/brand-vid-modulhus-for-nyanlanda-man-gripen/), [Aftonbladet](http://www.aftonbladet.se/nyheter/kolumnister/a/OKMdV/vill-vi-verkligen-tillbaka-till-en-tid-utan-kvinnliga-poliser), [Expressen](http://www.expressen.se/nyheter/stockholm/mannen-gar-till-attack-mot-polisen-med-sten/) and [SVT](http://www.svt.se/nyheter/lokalt/stockholm/misstankt-mordbrand-pa-asylboende-polis-skadad). [The press release](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:NK6soNNhuqkJ:https://polisen.se/Aktuellt/Handelser/Stockholms-lan/2017-03-20-0749-Brand-Stockholm/%20&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de&lr=lang_da%7Clang_de%7Clang_en%7Clang_no%7Clang_sv&client=firefox-b-ab) from the Stockholm Police is not published anymore, but can be found in Google's web cache.

The perpetrator was a resident of the housing complex (so, most likely a refugee) and was arrested and accused of arson, damage to property, violence against enforcement officer, attempted violence against enforcement officer and disturbance.

Comment: "and was arrested and accused of...." so the person in the video did not actually evade arrest, overall, which seems to be what was claimed or implied?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I am not sure if I understand your question. Isn't that exactly what I wrote?

Comment: It seems like it, but there was never any kind of explicit confirmation or rebuttal of the question asked ("he **tried** but did not succeed, so, no...." for example), so I wanted to make sure I was understanding your response correctly. Actual clarification requested, not any kind of snarky rhetorical question or implied criticism intended.